# Cannot Run my Hello World Program it Gives could not find or load main class (Classbot found Exception)

Tags: java

Cannot Run my Hello World Program it says "could not find or load main class (ClassnotfoundException)" My code is given Below.this program Compiled Successfully but did not run.(I am using CMD)

```
 public class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
{

 System.out.println("Hello World");
 }

 }
```

Comment: Please show us the command you're using to run it.

Comment: javac d:\CS506\HelloWorldApp.java

Comment: Remove `.class` from the end of the second command: `java d:\CS506\HelloWorldApp`

Comment: i have tried this as well

Comment: also, you should be in that directory or add it to the classpath, so `cd d:\CS506\ ` and then `java HelloWorldApp`

Comment: Navigate to the directory which has the class and run `java classname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the classpath drive separately to run it:

Try: `java -cp d:\ HelloWorldApp`

replace `d:\` with your path i.e. `java -cp d:\CS506 HelloWorldApp`

Comment: Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Thanks for all answers.

Comment: "java -cp d:\ HelloWorldApp" why do i have to write "-cp"